# Genymotion 3.0.2 and lost devices after reinstall ubuntu

Tags: genymotion

after reinstall ubuntu from zero (`/home` were at another partition and now used with new installation) and update Genymotion 3 to 3.0.2, list of installed devices now empty even after point to same folder it located.

my devices is stored at 
`/somepath/GenymotionDevices/deployed/`
and then

```
Custom Phone/
Google Pixel C/
...
```

I have point devices path to

`/somepath/
/somepath/GenymotionDevices/
/somepath/GenymotionDevices/deployed/`

but list of installed devices still empty.

what could be wrong? how could I restore my devices to be use in Genymotion again?

Comment: If you reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch all previous data in those partitions should be gone. So, nothing's wrong.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia how to restore my devices to be used in Genymotion again?

Comment: I don't even know what Genymotion is (I could google it but I don't see the point)... The point is what happened is normal and expected. Your last comment is an entirely different question to which I would guess the answer is you can't.

Comment: Not sure this helps but may provides clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538686/how-to-copy-virtual-devices-downloaded-by-genymotion-to-another-machine